# onActivityResult called before take photo

Tags: android, camera, onactivityresult

I need to take a photo then upload the photo to server. Something gets weird, because when I startActivityForResult as below, onActivityResult is just called immediately, I need it to be called when I done talking photos. Is it because my Activity is going to destroyed? What should I do? Thanks!

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_PHOTO);
```

Comment: what is requestCode, resultCode and data?

Comment: check your launchmode in the Manifest.xml, try android:launchMode="standard" in your activity.

Comment: Does it occur in every camera app? my though is that you don't know the third party implementation so you'll always need to make sure in the OnActivityResult the request code

Comment: Petrus's answer is right!Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is

```
android:launchMode="standard"
```

Thank Petrus.

Comment: I do not see standard as an option